# i keep getting a 401 when connecting to mailgun

Tags: node.js, api

I'm doing a course that does not allow mw to use libraries and npm so this is the https request I have crafted

```
helpers.mailgunSendEmail = (toEmail, toName, subject, message, callback) => {
      // validate parameters
      const emailRegex = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
      toEmail = typeof(toEmail) === 'string' && emailRegex.test(toEmail) ? toEmail.trim() : false;
      toName = typeof(toName) === 'string' && toName.trim().length > 2 ? toName.trim() : false;
      subject = typeof(subject) === 'string' && subject.trim().length > 2 ? subject.trim() : false;
      message = typeof(message) === 'string' && message.trim().length > 2 ? message.trim() : false;
      
    
      if (toEmail && toName && message) {
          // Configure the request payload
          const payload = {
              'from' : 'Pizza App <weixinpua0227@gmail.com>',
              'to' : "weixinpua0227@gmail.com",
              'subject' : subject,
              'text' : message
          };
    
          // Stringify the payload
          const stringPayload = querystring.stringify(payload);
          
          // Configure the request details
          const requestDetails = {
            'protocol' : 'https:',
            'hostname' : 'api.mailgun.net',
            'method' : 'POST',
            'auth' : config.mailgun.mailgunCredential,
            'path' : '/v3/' +config.mailgun.sandbox+ '/messages',
            'headers' : {
                'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-length' : Buffer.byteLength(stringPayload)
            }
            };
    
            // Instantiate the request object
            let req = https.request(requestDetails, res => {
                // Grab the status of the sent request
                let status = res.statusCode;
                
                // Callback successfully if the request went through
                if (status == 200 || status == 201) {
                    callback(false);
                } else {
                    callback(status);
                }
            });
```

this is how I call it

```
helpers.mailgunSendEmail("wxpua27@hotmail.com",'weixin','no subject','msg',(status)=>{
  console.log(status)
});
```

this is where the sandbox domain is stored

```
  mailgun:{
    sandbox:"sandboxa3a26706f4b74f75b015e91df2f31ebb.mailgun.org",
    mailgunCredential:"key-ba7409a41e533fcaecc0454cdf93475b"
  }
```

I hardcoded my `email(weixinpua0227@gmail.com)` into the code due to mailgun's sandbox only allowing mail to be sent to authorised user

my sandbox is also in US area so the hostname (api.mailgun.net) should be fine

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63489555/mailgun-401-forbidden) helps?

Comment: I have read this post before posting this question and I have checked that the zone that my sandbox domain is in is us, I have also checked that the email that I'm sending to is verified by the sandbox domain

Comment: In the link above there is a way to send the mail to yourself to check the the configuration is correct. I think you should run that first to check it basic config is appropriate.